# How to iterate through json file in python and return data based on a requirement?

Tags: python, json

I'm pretty new to python and still trying to figure out how to work with json files. Is there a way to iterate through this json file and grab everything based on a requirement? For example searching for all names with Jack?

This is the current json file:

```
{
  "city": "Seattle",
  "school": "Marley High",
  "people": [
     {  
       "Name" : "Jack Fronda",
       "Age" : "14",
     },
     {  
       "Name" : "Jack Sims",
       "Age" : "15",
     },
     {  
       "Name" : "Sarah Lee",
       "Age" : "15",
     },
     {  
       "Name" : "James Bill",
       "Age" : "20",
     }
 ]}
```

But I want to return just

```
{ [
   {
   "Name" : "Jack Fronda",
   "Age" : "14",
    },
   {  
       "Name" : "Jack Sims",
       "Age" : "15",
   }
]
```

}

this what i have so far:

```
import json

jsonFilePath = r"C:\Users\Downloads"
jsonFile = "test.json"

with open(jsonFilePath + "/" + jsonFile as fp:
 data = json.load(fp)
```

Comment: Your "expected output" is not valid JSON. Other than that, what **specific issues** are you having using `data` variable? See [help] on asking good questions

Comment: Also, your question is really unrelated to JSON. Create a [mcve]... E.g. Given `people = [{  "Name" : "Jack Fronda", "Age" : "14" }, { "Name" : "Sarah Lee", "Age" : "15"}]`, output your list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter function with a lambda expression

```py
import json

def query(requirement_function, data):
    return list(filter(requirement_function, data))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = None

    with open(r"C:\Users\Downloads\test.json") as f:
        content = f.read()
        data    = json.loads(content)

    result = query(lambda x: x["Name"].startswith("Jack"), data["people"])
```

Since you are new, I tried to keep the code simple.

Answer (score 0):

`json.load` returns a [`dict`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp). To get the list of people in that `dict` you should access `data['people']`. If you want the first two elements in the list you can do it with [slicing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-slicing/) like `data['people'][:2]`.